How to verify if the camera is calibrated?
I am trying to perform RGB camera calibrations with ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04.4 .
For this, I'm using cameras from LUCID connected with POE , model : Lucid Triton 54s-cc: https://thinklucid.com/product/triton-5-mp-imx490/
I use the ROS2 calibration tool: camera_calibration cameracalibrator
The result is save in a YAML file.
In my code, I use ArenaAPI.h to manipulate the camera.
But I use the library camera_info_manager.hpp for the validation, my code look like this :
camera calibration with camera info manager
  this->camera_info_ = std::shared_ptr<camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager>( new camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager(this));

  if(this->camera_info_->validateURL(this->camera_info_url))
  {
    this->camera_info_->loadCameraInfo(this->camera_info_url);
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Lucid triton driver - Camera calibration validated");
  }
  else
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Lucid triton driver - camera info url cannot be validate. Publishing with unconfigured camera");
  } 

with
std::string camera_info_url = "package://lucid_triton_driver/calibration/ost.yaml"
When i run my application, the URL(calibration file : ost.yaml) is validated, but I don't know if it really work.
Because with or without these lines of codes, the output images of the camera seem to be the same.

If someone can help me to find a way or a tools in ROS to verify if the camera is really calibrated?

Thanks for your help!
